# How to include file in Raku

Tags: perl-module, raku

I have two Raku files:

hello.p6:

```
sub hello
{
    say 'hello';
}
```

and main.p6:

```
require 'hello.p6';

hello();
```

But don't work. How to can include the first file in the main script?

Comment: can you clarify why it doesn't work? What error are you getting?

also, why not take a look at using packages and the Exporter module?

Comment: @Blaskovicz - perl6 doesn't use Exporter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using explicit file syntax and explicit export list seems to work for me in Rakudo:

main.p6:

```
require Hello:file('Hello.p6') <hello>;

hello();
```

hello.p6:

```
sub hello {
    say 'hello';
}
```

Source: http://perlcabal.org/syn/S11.html#Runtime_Importation

Comment: Hi @mvp, the raku doc on ``require``` states ```If MyModule doesn't export &something then require will fail.``` (https://docs.raku.org/syntax/require). I suggest we should check with one of the core team whether this code should be ```sub hello is export {```  there's either a bug in the doc ... or we should not rely on this even if it "seems to work" in the current version.

Answer (score 15):

Just for the record, the proper solution is to use a module:

File Hello.pm6

```
 module Hello;
 sub hello() is export {
     say 'hello';
 }
```

File hello.p6:

```
 use v6;
 use lib '.'; # to search for Hello.pm6 in the current dir
 use Hello;
 hello;
```